# C++ gap between arrays in stack

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, stack, mingw

Output of this code:

```
int a;
int b;
cout<<"a: "<<&a<<endl;
cout<<"b: "<<&b<<endl;
```

is:

```
a: 0x6ffe4c
b: 0x6ffe48
```

and it makes sense, difference should be 4 bytes between them, but the output of this code:

```
int A[1];
int B[1];
cout<<"A: "<<A<<endl;
cout<<"B: "<<B<<endl;
```

is:

```
A: 0x6ffe40
B: 0x6ffe30
```

so now the difference is 16 bytes, can anyone explain why? why is that gap needed? I didn't know that there's a gap in stack when you allocate arrays like this and thought that in this case B[1] is the same as A[0].

Comment: Which compiler do you use?

Comment: Mingw port of GCC

Comment: Version? Maybe the compiler aligns int arrays to 16, so it can generate aligned SSE load instructions for them (which is not useful for your case though, because array size is 1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For explanation of gaps between array variables *in your instance*, you will need to research how GNU C++ compiler allocates memory for variables.  Allocation of variables depends on the compiler.

Some reasons (not inclusive) for gaps between variables:

### Alignment

Processors are more efficient when they can fetch from addresses aligned to their word size.  For example, a processor with 32-bit word likes to fetch from 4-byte aligned addresses.  Accessing 32-bits from address 5 would require two fetches and then some byte shifting to place the bytes in the correct order.

### Data segments

A constant variable may be placed in the executable or a read-only data segment.  It may be declared next to a read/write variable and thus have a log of gap between them.

### Overrun space

A compiler may allocate space after an array to provide for "buffering" in case of array overruns.

### Meta information

The compiler may choose to place attributes (Meta) information about the data type after the data type (or before).  For example, when dynamically allocating memory for an array, the compiler may choose to place the size of the allocation near the array (useful for recovering the memory).

### Registers

The compiler may place variables in registers.  Thus the variables would have different addresses since registers aren't usually in the same memory map; although there are processors that have memory mapped registers.

### Parsing

Variables may be allocated in locations convenient for parsing.  A compiler may delay variable allocation until convenient or the location may be changed during an optimization pass.

Answer (score 3):

Neither C nor C++ makes any guarantees about the order of automatic variables in memory, or about any padding between them. These are implementation details of your particular compiler.

Comment: The downvoter might like to indicate which sentence in this short answer they disagree with.

Comment: The question is: "can anyone explain why? why is that gap needed?". Your answer is not useful to answer these questions.